# Unix: User and group name for a folder and any of its new file

Tags: unix, file-permissions, chmod

I have a folder *xyz* with *root* as its user and *abc* as its group. I have say 3 users, *a*, *b*, *c* who belong to the group *abc*. The folder has permission as 775, which means any user in the group can write into the folder.

The problem I am having is, when say, user *a* uploads a file in the folder *xyz*, the file has *a* as its user and as its group as well. Which means, user *b* will bot be able to edit the file.

So what can we do to ensure that any new file which gets uploaded in the folder *xyz* has by default *abc* as its group name?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it depends of your ftp server configuration. In fact, I know that it is in vsftpd configuration file, but I don't know for the other ftp servers. Maybe you should ask in http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the setgid bit on the directory. Newly created files will inherit the group of the directory rather than the primary group of the user creating the file.

```
chmod g+s /path/to/xyz
```

Comment: agree with above, but would amplify that it sounds like your user b has his own primary group of b, so if you can change users a,b,c to have primary group of abc, then no need to chmod .... Good luck to all.